# Using MUI v5 sx Prop to Set CSS Property with Multiple Values (e.g. margin, border-radius, etc...)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, sx

Is there a cleaner way to write the following that takes advantage of the sx prop's access to spacing units?

```
<MUIComponent sx={{ borderRadius: '4px 8px 12px 16px' }} />
```

Something like this?

```
<MUIComponent sx={{ borderRadius: [1, 2, 3, 4] }} />
```

I can't find anything in [the docs](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/), but I'd be surprised if this feature doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you are very close! You can use your theme to set the amounts of borderRadius.
https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties

From the docs link above: "The borderRadius property multiplies the value it receives by the `theme.shape.borderRadius` value (the default for this value is 4px)."

```
<Box sx={{ borderRadius: 2 }} />
// equivalent to borderRadius: '8px'
```

To add multiple borders, for top, left, etc: https://mui.com/system/borders/#additive

or you can import your theme to the component and use theme.spacing (https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/spacing/#custom-spacing):

```
<MUIComponent sx={{ borderRadius: theme.spacing(1, 2, 3, 4) }} />
```